# Resttemplate not pegging http_client metrics

Tags: resttemplate, metrics

I am using Resttemplate to communicate with other applications. I am not seeing http_client_response metrics pegged in our application. I also tried RestTemplateBuilder and even that did not work. Could you please help me in resolving this issue?

I am expecting http_client_response metrics which shows the status of the request and response in prometheus metrics.

Tried with RestTemplateBuilder as well. With webclient i can see this metrics but i have a requirement where i should do this with restTemplate / restemplatebuilder only.